# Multiple Parameters in WCF Service json

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I am trying to consume a WCF service from a Window Form. The method that I am trying to call accepts two parameters:

```
public String Redirect(String code, String[] data)
{
   //Some code here.
}
```

Now , when I try to connect to the function, sending no data, the web service stops. I need to know how to send the data with the correct format so the function accepts de connection.

PT: The function only accepts json data.

The code I am using to conect to the web service :

```
            String url = GetUrl();
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "POST";
            System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
            request.GetResponse();
```

thanks

Comment: How are you making this call? Add the code that executes your call to the webservice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you used `WebInvoke` with an `POST` method. The solution is quite simple: You forgot to add the message to the body:

```
String url = GetUrl();
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Method = "POST";

byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Your JSON data");
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
```

`You JSON data` would be something like this:

```
{
    "code": "10",
    "data": [
        "hello",
        "data"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. In the "Your JSON data", how do I add both parameters? . Searching a little bit, i found that some people use :                 
using (var StreamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    StreamWriter.Write(data);
                }

Comment: See my answer. Just change the value of "You JSON data" to "{\"code\": \"10\",\"data\": [\"hello\",\"data\"]}"

Comment: However, using the StreamWriter would also be a solution